# implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed WHEN $_POST['duration'] == EMPTY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiselect field

```
<select name="duration[]" id="duration" title="Duration" multiple="multiple" size="3">
<option value="1">1 Months</option>
<option value="2">2 Months</option>
<option value="3">3 Months</option>
</select>
```

my php code implode multiple values i.e 123 as 1,2,3 and insert it in database. The problem is that the field is not a required field and when i leave it empty it give me error (Invalid arguments passed)

My php code below

```
$duration = array();
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
if($duration)
   {
   foreach($duration as $value)
   {
   $months[] = $value;
   }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses WHERE duration IN (".implode($months, ',').") ";
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two problems you have is you try to implode on user input which may not be an array, and your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

To address those you should first check if it's an array with `is_array()`, then check if it has  any elements with `count()`, then finally implode but use `array_map()` to filter the values to prevent SQL Injection. This will not only prevent SQL Injection but will prevent syntax errors in your query because strings must be quoted in an `IN` clause.

```
function getInt($i) {
    return (int)$i;
}

$inClause = '';

if(isset($_POST['duration']) && is_array($_POST['duration']) && count($_POST['duration']) > 0)
{
    $inClause = 'WHERE ';
    $inClause .= implode(', ', array_map('getInt', $_POST['duration']));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses $inClause";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$duration = array();
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$sql = FALSE;
if($duration&&is_array($duration))
   {
   foreach($duration as $value)
   {
   $months[] = $value;
   }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses WHERE duration IN (".implode($months, ',').") ";
}

if($sql){
//do something with sql
}
```

use is_array to check if $duration is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the WHERE condition if it is not required

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses";

if (count($months)>0)
    $sql .= " WHERE duration IN (".implode($months, ',').") ";
```

and better use `isset($_POST["x"])` instead of just an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say `$_POST['duration']` is `null`.

```
$duration = array();
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
```

Then you don't have a value to implode on because your `foreach` is not going to be executed. 
One solution would be to put your code into an `if( $_POST['duration'] )` respectively `if( count($months) )`

Comment: by applying if condition, my query look like this "SELECT * FROM tbl_courses WHERE duration IN ()"  and it cause the above error

Comment: you would also put the query in your condition then, and have an else where you have another query, maybe without `IN`...

Comment: i cant put my query in condition because i in case if i have multiple fields in my form then how i will concatenate these different queries

Answer (score 0):

One of options is typecasting.

```
$duration = (array)$_POST['duration'];
```

Since you use contents of $_POST['duration'] in your query be aware of SQL injection techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `$_POST['duration']` is set and build your WHERE statement if it is, if not leave it blank:

```
$where = !$_POST['duration'] ? '' : 'WHERE duration IN ('.implode($_POST['duration'],',').')';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_courses '.$where;
```

I have also removed some of your unnecessary variable declaration and looping around `$duration`.

Please note you need to sanitise your data to protect against SQL injection. The easiest way in this case would to be to loop through the values and cast them as `int`:

```
foreach($_POST['duration'] as $value) {
   $months[] = (int)$value;
}
$where = !$months ? '' : 'WHERE duration IN ('.implode($months,',').')';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_courses '.$where;
```